# Field for sorting criteria in views with "node views count" module

Tags: views

I'm using [Node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) module to get the count of each node being visited by users.

I have created a view which shows listings filtered with specific content type and I wanted to add most viewed field for sorting criteria but it looks like [Node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) module does not provide such fields which can be used in views for sorting the list based on the most visited nodes.

Is it possible to achieve this with [Node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) module or do I need to use any other module. Please suggest, Thanks In advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the module you're using, but you might want to try Google Analytics Counter. https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter